# Inconsistencies in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I was wondering why this NSPredicate works:

```
let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company = '1'")
```

But not this one:

```
let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company = '%@'", 1)
```

And also this:

```
let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company = '%@'", company)
```

When I print the value of company. The output is Optional(1).

So why does the first line of code works?

Comment: Define 'works'. E.g. with the second one, what did you do subsequently to conclude that it doesn't work? In the third case the answer is likely as simple as unwrapping the company but I'm struggling to imagine an issue with the second.

Comment: It works because it successfully fetches my record from coredata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the "Predicate Programming Guide":

> Single or double quoting variables ... cause %@, %K, or $variable to be interpreted as a literal in the format string and so prevent any substitution.

So in your second predicate, you compare the "company" property
against the literal string `"%@"`:

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "company = '%@'", 1)
print(p1) // company == "%@"
```

To compare against an integer, use

```
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "company = %@", NSNumber(integer: 1))
print(p2) // company == 1
```

or

```
let p3 = NSPredicate(format: "company = %ld", 1)
```

Comment: What if I want to use the variable `company` instead of the number 1?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo: You can do the same with a variable. Use the `%ld` format for an `Int`, and `%@` for an `NSNumber` (or other `NSObject`  subclasses).

Comment: So that would be: `let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "company = %@", NSNumber(integer: company))` ?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo: It depends on the type of the `company` variable, see my previous comment.

Comment: It is a parameter in the function: `func get_facility(company: String!, territory: String!)`

Comment: @JaysonTamayo: Then it is a string and `NSPredicate(format: "company = %@", company)` should work.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo: Did you remove the single-quotes inside the format string?

Comment: Yes, I removed it.

Comment: This: `company == "Optional(1)"`

Comment: @JaysonTamayo: Then `company` contains the string "Optional(1)", which means that the problem is where you create that string, not with the predicate.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo: Did you make any progress on this problem?

Comment: Yes. I ended up using NSNumber